# I can't unset inherited private variables; even with reflection

Tags: php

```
class A
{
    private $a;
}

class B extends A
{
    function __construct()
    {
        (new \ReflectionClass($this))->getProperty('a')->setAccessible(true);
        unset($this->a); // fatal error
    }
}

(new B());
```

This triggers a fatal error although I did change the accessibility

Comment: Instead of `inheriting` the class, instead, 'compose' your class by using the class by injecting it and then using the parts of it that you want to. It is a lot easier to maintain. Especially if you use `interfaces`.

Answer (score 1):

No, no you can't. `$a` exists *only* in the symbol table for instances of `class A`, but `new B` gives you an instance of `class B`. From the perspective of your object `new B`, `$a` doesn't exist by definition: thus `unset($this->a)` is *de facto* impossible.